# How to get selected value of a html select with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, html-select

I have code below:

```
<select id="testSelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test it!" onclick="btnTest_Click" />
```

I need to get selected options' value on postback. How can I do this with asp.net?

Comment: Great... How about Multiple values ???

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to add a name to your `<select>` element:

```
<select id="testSelect" name="testSelect">
```

It will be posted to the server, and you can see it using:

```
Request.Form["testSelect"]
```

Comment: No problem. Pontus makes a valid point about using a server-side Drop-Down, if possible, but I assumed you had a good reason not to use it.

Comment: Any Luck with multiple values selected by user ?!

Comment: @jalchr - For multiple values you can use `Request.Form.GetValues("testSelect")`. In the future, you can probably ask a new question, it will get you a faster answer.

Comment: That doesn't work for me; if interested, see Update 3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655000/how-can-i-get-the-text-of-the-selected-item-in-an-html-select-element

Answer (score 10):

I've used this solution to get what you need.

Let'say that in my .aspx code there's a select list runat="server":

```
<select id="testSelect"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" required>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

In my C# code I used the code below to retrieve the text and also value of the options:

```
testSelect.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "uninformed" : 
    testSelect.Items[testSelect.SelectedIndex].Text);
```

In this case I check if the user selected any of the options. If there's nothing selected I show the text as "uninformed".

Comment: As you can see the question is about a select with no runat server attribute.

Comment: yeah, I know, I was just showing another aproach for achieving the same result. Thanks for the comment = )

Answer (score 8):

If you would use `asp:dropdownlist` you could select it easier by `testSelect.Text`.

Now you'd have to do a `Request.Form["testSelect"]` to get the value after pressed `btnTes`.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: You need to specify a `name` of the select (not only ID) to be able to `Request.Form["testSelect"]`

Comment: `name` did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
<head>
    <title> HtmlSelect Example </title>
    <script runat="server">
      void Button_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Label1.Text = "Selected index: " + Select1.SelectedIndex.ToString()
                       + ", value: " + Select1.Value;    
      }    
   </script>    
</head>    
<body>    
   <form id="form1" runat="server">

      Select an item: 

      <select id="Select1" runat="server">    
         <option value="Text for Item 1" selected="selected"> Item 1 </option>
         <option value="Text for Item 2"> Item 2 </option>
         <option value="Text for Item 3"> Item 3 </option>
         <option value="Text for Item 4"> Item 4 </option>
      </select>

      <button onserverclick="Button_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>

      <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"/>    
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Source from Microsoft. Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Java script:

use  `elementid. selectedIndex()`  function to get the selected index