# How to get selected index of a Html select in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code below:

```
 <select id="test">
        <option value="a">aaa</option>
        <option value="b">bbb</option>
    </select>
    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test it!" onclick="btnTest_Click" />
```

I need to get selected index not selected value on postback. How can I do this with asp.net?
this is my code for filling the select html:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=btnTest.ClientID %>").click(function(){
    $.ajax(
    { url: "StateCity.asmx/ReferItems?id=" + getParameterByName('id'),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
        $("#test").empty();
        $.each(data.d, function() {
        $("#test").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });

        },
        error: function() { alert("Error"); }
    }) 
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378338/how-to-get-selected-value-of-a-html-select-with-asp-net

Comment: yes but it's talking about selected value. but I want selected index

Answer (score 5):

1. Add `runat="server"` attribute to the `<select>`
2. In code behind (button handler code) do:

```cs
int selectedIndex = (test as HtmlSelect).SelectedIndex;
```

**EDIT:** Answer to comment regarding `-1` value of the SelectedIndex property

MSDN [HtmlSelect.SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.selectedindex.aspx):

> It is possible to have no item selected. If no item is selected, the
>   SelectedIndex property contains **a value of -1**. This commonly
>   occurs when the page first loads and an item is not selected by
>   default. Provide code to test this value before referencing the item
>   in the Items collection. Otherwise, an exception is thrown if the
>   index is out of the range of the collection.

Comment: but it returns -1 always. for selected value I use Request.Form[test.UniqueID]. but what should I do for selected index.

Comment: See HTML source whether any option has `selected="true"`

Comment: No there is no selected="true"

Comment: I fill the select html using jquery. what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Add a runat attribute to your Selct HTML control so that it can be accessable in the codebehind.

```
 <select id="test" runat="server">
      <option value="a">aaa</option>
      <option value="b">bbb</option>
        <option value="c">cc</option>
    </select>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
string dd = test.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

This code is tested. :)